# Python cx_Oracle equivalent of ROracle::dbsendquery?

Tags: python, r, cx-oracle, roracle

I am using cx-oralce right now and I have to execute a sql statement.
For R, sendquery and getinfo are used for it and also to check if the execution is complete or not. Is there something similar in Python that I can do with cx-oralce?
I need to be able to see if the execution is complete or not!

```
rs = ROracle::dbSendQuery(conn, sql)

if (!ROracle::dbGetInfo(rs)$completed) {
    msg <- "Failed "
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With cx_Oracle, you would do the following:

```
try:
    conn.execute(sql)
except cx_Oracle.DatabaseError as e:
    print("Failed:", e)
```